# iOS build Error - Multiple Build Commands

Tags: ios, iphone, build

i am getting the following build error

[image]

I imported the Project after cloning from the GIT. and i tried to build the project but it fails.

Comment: r u opening workspace generated by cocoapods ?

Comment: no it was used in xcode by my developer. @DheerajSingh

Comment: u must have added cocoapods into ur project and it would have genertaed a workspace.

Comment: how do we solve this? @DheerajSingh

Comment: do u have any workspace to ur project

Answer (score 1):

You should open in terminal folder with your project and execute

```
pod install
```

If that command does not run, check at http://cocoapods.org/ Install section. Then open xcworkspace file instead of xcodeproj